# How to start a web server in the current folder on the command line using Node or ClojureScript?

Tags: python, node.js, command-line, clojurescript

To start a web server in the current directory on the command line, I'm using:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

I'd like to do this using Node or ClojureScript.

My question is: **How to start a web server in the current folder on the command line using Node or ClojureScript?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [Big list of http static server one-liners](https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255)

> ```
> $ npm install -g http-server   # install dependency
> $ http-server -p 8000
> ```

or

> ```
> $ npm install -g node-static   # install dependency
> $ static -p 8000
> ```

Comment: lein simpleton 8080 - nice! https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255#gistcomment-1219420